# Drive won't mount after passphrase

Tags: freeze

I have enjoyed my time with linux and the learning process.  So much so, that i setup a profile for my son.  Not sure what he did, or if he even did anything.

When starting up, i get to the point where i enter the passphrase, i do so, and it sits.  I can press s to skip mounting(which does nothing), and i think m to recover or have further option, neither of which prove fruitful.

It's like it just freezes after the encryption passphrase is entered.

Whats the deal with that?  What do i do?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is it the login passphrase, or one for disk encryption, bios etc? Do you know what your son did if anything?

Comment: He likes to play a lot of online games, from what i consider shady sites.

Comment: He also has a flashdrive that he likes to tote around claiming his "stuff" is saved on it.

Comment: I didnt see anything on it.  I will try the ctrl+alt+f's and see what happens. After the passphrase is entered, it looks and acts normal, the 4-5 with dots under the ubuntu, turns red one after another and repeats.  It just never go's anywhere afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, guess i shouldve read everything before posting.  Its the encryption passphrase, before you get to the login password.

Comment: Alright, the ctrl+alt+F's change to black with a fast blinking cursor, then back.  Thats it.

Comment: Can you access the partitions on the hard disk from a Live install DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Can you **`Ctrl+Alt+F3`** to enter a TTY console after it "freezes"? Try going into one and going back with **`Ctrl+Alt+F1`** or **`Ctrl+Alt+F7`**

Comment: This switched to a black screen with a fast blinking cursor, then back.